# data count from two different table by group by

Tags: mysql

i have two table a,b and both tables structure is same as below

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| srno      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| domain    | varchar(50)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| timestamp | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| source    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

i want domain count from both table on particular date
so plz help

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  "domain count . . . on particular date" isn't really clear.

Answer (score 2):

I think the tricky part of the question is that you need `union all` to bring the tables together.  The rest of the question is unclear.  If I interpret it as getting all domains with their counts on one particular day:

```
select domain, count(*)
from ((select a.* from a) union all
      (select b.* from b)
     ) ab
where timestamp >= $YOURDATE and
      timestamp < date_add($YOURDATE, interval 1 day)
group by domain;
```

Note:  Having two tables with exactly the same structure is usually a sign of poor database design.  A single entity is usually placed in a single table.  More typically, there would be one table with a column specifying "a" or "b".